# Highcharts - For Area chart yAxis.min is always set to 0

Tags: highcharts

After updating Highcharts to newer versions (e.g. 9.0.0+/10.3.2), min value for yAxis for area chart is always set to 0 and for large values the chart looks like stright line without extremes. For line chart type, chart looks ok.

Please see example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular14-standaone-components-highcharts-vwctmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

On version 7.2.2 for area chart, min value was automatically calculated based on input data.

Is it a bug?
How can I set options to force min value to be automatically calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `threshold` property to `null`.

From Highcharts API:

> **threshold**: number, null
>
> The Y axis value to serve as the base for the area, for distinguishing
> between values above and below a threshold. The area between the graph
> and the threshold is filled.
>
> - If a number is given, the Y axis will scale to the threshold.
> - If null, the scaling behaves like a line series with fill between the graph and the Y axis minimum.
> - If Infinity or -Infinity, the area between the graph and the corresponding Y axis extreme is filled (since v6.1.0).
>
> Defaults to 0.

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    threshold: null
  }]
```

Discussion about `softThreshold`: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15061

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9cnmxqks/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.threshold

Answer (score 1):

Area chart with softThreshold on Highcharts 7.2.1 has the yAxis starting point as auto-calculation value (the same as Line chart) but from 8.2.2 and higher yAxis Area chart always starts from 0

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
            'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        softThreshold: true,
        data: [9990, 9150, 10640, 12920, 14400, 17600, 13560, 14850, 21640,19410, 9960, 9440]
    }]   
});
```

7.2.1 example: https://jsfiddle.net/6v7gd8m0/5/

8.2.2 example: https://jsfiddle.net/b0tz3dfq/

Does anyone know how to make yAxis of an Area chart start with auto-calculation value and not always with 0?

======================
EDIT ======================

From 8.2.2 and higher softThreshold seems to work opposite so with softThreshold set to false
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0keanhs2/

Does anyone understands why in that case softThreshold seem to have opposite result when switching from version 7 to 8?